# How to parse XML in android with the url image and text and frame it in a List view

Tags: android, listview, xml-parsing, imageview

Can any one tell me how to parse an XML file which has a url of the image and also two text and i have to parse and display it in the list view. Can any one please show me with coding, as am a beginner and i want to do this task. This is not static but dynamic in which iwill  have the url and i just have to parse that from my android application and display it in List View. Thanks in advance. If anyone could help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of adapter you're using.  If you're using a built in adapter, it should take a layout resource id.  If you're building your own, use this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.call_list_view, null);
        }
            //initialize the view values here
  }
```

Comment: Actually i don't from where to start if you could provide me the full code and any url which parses and displayed it in the list view then it would be very nice.